# Updated to Mantic Minotaur; grub kernel entries missing

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kernel

I just upgraded to 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur) and it seemed to work fine. I rebooted and there are no kernel entries to choose from at the grub menu - just memory tests, my windows partition, and the UEFI entry. I did see the installer ask me about the grub menu and I believe I mistakenly chose to keep my local file.
Anyway, can anyone offer some advice?
Thanks.

Comment: Run Ubuntu from a live USB, and run the boot repair tool https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Consider running `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Ok. I'm trying Boot-Repair and here is the log file: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hhC47BXws7/

Comment: I've mounted my root drive (and dev and proc, etc) and chrooted into it and ran update-grub:

/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux: 1: version_find_latest: not found

Comment: Congrest playing around with grub-customizer. Remove any folder and file with Proxy in Name  under /etc/grub.d/.And run in correct chroot `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Does "proxified" mean anything to you? It doesn't sound standard. I don't have that subfolder in any of my /etc/grub.d folders. This suggests to me that you installed something that is causing your issue.

Comment: Yes that too. 

Comment: What does 'Congrest' mean? I have '10_linux_proxy' and 'proxifiedScripts'. Is this what you mean?

Comment: The error message you posted in the comments shows that update-grub is looking for something in a folder in /etc/grub.d called proxifiedScripts.  That's not a standard Ubuntu configuration, so you must have installed something that added it. You'll need to figure out what that was and then how to fix it.

Comment: I've read that proxifiedScripts comes from grub-customizer. I've already deleted that package. 10_linux_proxy is referring to proxifiedScripts so I'm assuming I should delete both and run upgrade-grub. At this point I dont have any grub menu left at all so I can't even access my windows partition.

Comment: Ouch, grub-customizer is legendary for causing problems. I have always steered clear of it so I don't know how to recover from removing it. This web page suggests to do a clean install if grub-customizer has hosed your system https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/grub-customizer.html

Comment: Running update-grub is not adding my linux kernels or my windows partition back in. ffs.

Comment: That webpage I linked specifically says that removing grub-customizer doesn't undo the changes it made to grub.

Comment: Can you at least tell me the correct command for reinstalling grub for efi systems?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1355032/after-using-grub-customizer-how-do-i-recover-the-zfs-grub2-menu-options-on-ubun. Please try this.

Comment: Decided to do a reinstall. Thanks for all your help, guys. Truly a great community.